# ursina: how to save rendered frames as image or video?

Tags: python, game-engine, ursina

In ursina, How can I save the render frames as a sequence of images or a video? [Ursina cheat sheet](https://www.ursinaengine.org/cheat_sheet.html) has nothing on this.

Answer (score 2):

You can see [`VideoRecorder`](https://www.ursinaengine.org/cheat_sheet_dark.html#VideoRecorder) :

```
from ursina import *
import os, shutil
import numpy as np
# import imageio    # gets imported in convert_to_gif
# from panda3d.core import PNMImage

class VideoRecorder(Entity):
    def __init__(self, duration=5, name='untitled_video', **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.recording = False
        self.file_path = Path(application.asset_folder) / 'video_temp'
        self.i = 0
        self.duration = duration
        self.fps = 30
        self.video_name = name
        self.t = 0

        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)

        self.max_frames = int(self.duration * self.fps)
        self.frames = []


    def start_recording(self):
        print('start recording,', self.duration, self.file_path)
        window.fps_counter.enabled = False
        window.exit_button.visible = False
        self.frames = []
        self.max_frames = self.duration * self.fps
        if not self.file_path.exists():
            self.file_path.mkdir()
        base.movie(namePrefix=f'\\video_temp\\{self.video_name}', duration=2.0, fps=30, format='png', sd=4)

        self.recording = True
        invoke(self.stop_recording, delay=self.duration)


    def stop_recording(self):
        self.recording = False
        window.fps_counter.enabled = True
        window.exit_button.visible = True
        print('stop recording')
        self.convert_to_gif()


    def update(self):
        if not self.recording:
            return

            self.t += time.dt
            if self.t >= 1/30:
                base.screenshot(
                    namePrefix = '\\video_temp\\' + self.video_name + '_' + str(self.i).zfill(4) + '.png',
                    defaultFilename = 0,
                    )
                self.t = 0
        # # self.frames.append(self.renderToPNM())
        # image = base.win.getScreenshot()
        # data = image.getRamImageAs("RGB").getData()
        # # from PIL import Image
        # # image = Image.fromarray(data)
        # # img = data.convert("RGBA")
        # data = np.array(data)
        #
        # # image = deepcopy(camera.render_texture)
        # self.frames.append(data)
        self.i += 1

    # store screenshot in memory
    # def renderToPNM(self):
        # base.graphicsEngine.renderFrame()
        # if hasattr(camera, 'render_texure'):
        #     return copy(camera.render_texure)
        # # image = PNMImage()
        # # dr = base.camNode.getDisplayRegion(0)
        # # dr.getScreenshot(image)
        # # win.setupRenderTexture()
        # return None


    def convert_to_gif(self):
        import imageio
        images = []
        if not os.path.exists(self.file_path):
            return

        for filename in os.listdir(self.file_path):
            images.append(imageio.imread(self.file_path/filename))

        imageio.mimsave(Path(f'{self.file_path.parent}/{self.video_name}.gif'), images)
        shutil.rmtree(self.file_path)   # delete temp folder
        print('saved gif to:', Path(f'{self.file_path.parent}/{self.video_name}.gif'))



class VideoRecorderUI(WindowPanel):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.duration_label = Text('duration:')
        self.duration_field = InputField(default_value='5')
        self.fps_label = Text('fps:')
        self.fps_field = InputField(default_value='30')
        self.name_label = Text('name:')
        self.name_field = InputField(default_value='untitled_video')

        self.start_button = Button(text='Start Recording [Shift+F12]', color=color.azure, on_click=self.start_recording)

        super().__init__(
            title='Video Recorder [F12]',
            content=(
                self.duration_label,
                self.duration_field,
                self.fps_label,
                self.fps_field,
                self.name_label,
                self.name_field,
                Space(1),
                self.start_button,
                ),
            )
        self.y = .5
        self.scale *= .75
        self.visible = False


    def input(self, key):
        if key == 'f12':
            self.visible = not self.visible

        if held_keys['shift'] and key == 'f12':
            self.start_button.on_click()


    def start_recording(self):
        print(self.name_field)
        if self.name_field.text == '':
            self.name_field.blink(color.color(0,1,1,.5), .5)
            print('enter name')
            return

        # self.start_button.color=color.lime
        self.visible = False
        application.video_recorder.duration = float(self.duration_field.text)
        application.video_recorder.video_name = self.name_field.text
        application.video_recorder.frame_skip = 60 // int(self.fps_field.text)
        application.video_recorder.recording = True




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Ursina()
    # window.size = (1600/3,900/3)
    # cube = primitives.RedCube()
    # cube.animate_x(5, duration=5, curve=curve.linear)
    # cube.animate_x(0, duration=5, curve=curve.linear, delay=5)
    # vr = VideoRecorder()
    # invoke(setattr, vr, 'recording', True, delay=1)
    # invoke(os._exit, 0, delay=6)
    # vr.recording = True
    window.size *= .5
    from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController
    from ursina.shaders import lit_with_shadows_shader
    random.seed(0)
    Entity.default_shader = lit_with_shadows_shader

    ground = Entity(model='plane', collider='box', scale=64, texture='grass', texture_scale=(4,4))

    editor_camera = EditorCamera(enabled=False, ignore_paused=True)
    player = FirstPersonController(model='cube', z=-10, color=color.orange, origin_y=-.5, speed=8)
    player.collider = BoxCollider(player, Vec3(0,1,0), Vec3(1,2,1))

    gun = Entity(model='cube', parent=camera, position=(.5,-.25,.25), scale=(.3,.2,1), origin_z=-.5, color=color.red, on_cooldown=False)

    shootables_parent = Entity()
    mouse.traverse_target = shootables_parent

    for i in range(16):
        Entity(model='cube', origin_y=-.5, scale=2, texture='brick', texture_scale=(1,2),
            x=random.uniform(-8,8),
            z=random.uniform(-8,8) + 8,
            collider='box',
            scale_y = random.uniform(2,3),
            color=color.hsv(0, 0, random.uniform(.9, 1))
            )


    sun = DirectionalLight()
    sun.look_at(Vec3(1,-1,-1))
    Sky()

    vr = VideoRecorder(duration=10)
    def input(key):
        if key == '5':
            vr.start_recording()
        if key == '6':
            vr.stop_recording()



    app.run()
```

Comment: Thanks Tanay. This example creates a png. How can I get the frames instead of a png file?

Comment: @Saikat do you want a mp4 file ??

Answer (score 1):

This code will convert the recording to mp4 video:

```
from ursina import *
import os, shutil
import numpy as np
# import imageio    # gets imported in convert_to_gif
# from panda3d.core import PNMImage

class VideoRecorder(Entity):
    def __init__(self, duration=5, name='untitled_video', **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.recording = False
        self.file_path = Path(application.asset_folder) / 'video_temp'
        self.i = 0
        self.duration = duration
        self.fps = 30
        self.video_name = name
        self.t = 0

        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)

        self.max_frames = int(self.duration * self.fps)
        self.frames = []


    def start_recording(self):
        print('start recording,', self.duration, self.file_path)
        window.fps_counter.enabled = False
        window.exit_button.visible = False
        self.frames = []
        self.max_frames = self.duration * self.fps
        if not self.file_path.exists():
            self.file_path.mkdir()
        base.movie(namePrefix=f'\\video_temp\\{self.video_name}', duration=2.0, fps=30, format='png', sd=4)

        self.recording = True
        invoke(self.stop_recording, delay=self.duration)


    def stop_recording(self):
        self.recording = False
        window.fps_counter.enabled = True
        window.exit_button.visible = True
        print('stop recording')
        # self.convert_to_gif()
        self.convert_to_vid()


    def update(self):
        if not self.recording:
            return

            self.t += time.dt
            if self.t >= 1/30:
                base.screenshot(
                    namePrefix = '\\video_temp\\' + self.video_name + '_' + str(self.i).zfill(4) + '.png',
                    defaultFilename = 0,
                    )
                self.t = 0
        self.i += 1



    def convert_to_gif(self):
        import imageio
        images = []
        if not os.path.exists(self.file_path):
            return

        for filename in os.listdir(self.file_path):
            images.append(imageio.imread(self.file_path/filename))

        imageio.mimsave(Path(f'{self.file_path.parent}/{self.video_name}.gif'), images)
        shutil.rmtree(self.file_path)   # delete temp folder
        print('saved gif to:', Path(f'{self.file_path.parent}/{self.video_name}.gif'))

        
    def convert_to_vid(self):
        import imageio
        images = []
        if not os.path.exists(self.file_path):
            return


        writer = imageio.get_writer('test.mp4', fps=self.fps)
        for file in os.listdir(self.file_path):
            im = imageio.imread(self.file_path/file)
            writer.append_data(im)
        writer.close()
        print('Video saved!!')

class VideoRecorderUI(WindowPanel):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.duration_label = Text('duration:')
        self.duration_field = InputField(default_value='5')
        self.fps_label = Text('fps:')
        self.fps_field = InputField(default_value='30')
        self.name_label = Text('name:')
        self.name_field = InputField(default_value='untitled_video')

        self.start_button = Button(text='Start Recording [Shift+F12]', color=color.azure, on_click=self.start_recording)

        super().__init__(
            title='Video Recorder [F12]',
            content=(
                self.duration_label,
                self.duration_field,
                self.fps_label,
                self.fps_field,
                self.name_label,
                self.name_field,
                Space(1),
                self.start_button,
                ),
            )
        self.y = .5
        self.scale *= .75
        self.visible = False


    def input(self, key):
        if key == 'f12':
            self.visible = not self.visible

        if held_keys['shift'] and key == 'f12':
            self.start_button.on_click()


    def start_recording(self):
        print(self.name_field)
        if self.name_field.text == '':
            self.name_field.blink(color.color(0,1,1,.5), .5)
            print('enter name')
            return

        # self.start_button.color=color.lime
        self.visible = False
        application.video_recorder.duration = float(self.duration_field.text)
        application.video_recorder.video_name = self.name_field.text
        application.video_recorder.frame_skip = 60 // int(self.fps_field.text)
        application.video_recorder.recording = True




if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Ursina()
    # window.size = (1600/3,900/3)
    # cube = primitives.RedCube()
    # cube.animate_x(5, duration=5, curve=curve.linear)
    # cube.animate_x(0, duration=5, curve=curve.linear, delay=5)
    # vr = VideoRecorder()
    # invoke(setattr, vr, 'recording', True, delay=1)
    # invoke(os._exit, 0, delay=6)
    # vr.recording = True
    window.size *= .5
    from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController
    from ursina.shaders import lit_with_shadows_shader
    random.seed(0)
    Entity.default_shader = lit_with_shadows_shader

    ground = Entity(model='plane', collider='box', scale=64, texture='grass', texture_scale=(4,4))

    editor_camera = EditorCamera(enabled=False, ignore_paused=True)
    player = FirstPersonController(model='cube', z=-10, color=color.orange, origin_y=-.5, speed=8)
    player.collider = BoxCollider(player, Vec3(0,1,0), Vec3(1,2,1))

    gun = Entity(model='cube', parent=camera, position=(.5,-.25,.25), scale=(.3,.2,1), origin_z=-.5, color=color.red, on_cooldown=False)

    shootables_parent = Entity()
    mouse.traverse_target = shootables_parent

    for i in range(16):
        Entity(model='cube', origin_y=-.5, scale=2, texture='brick', texture_scale=(1,2),
            x=random.uniform(-8,8),
            z=random.uniform(-8,8) + 8,
            collider='box',
            scale_y = random.uniform(2,3),
            color=color.hsv(0, 0, random.uniform(.9, 1))
            )


    sun = DirectionalLight()
    sun.look_at(Vec3(1,-1,-1))
    Sky()

    vr = VideoRecorder(duration=10)
    def input(key):
        if key == '5':
            vr.start_recording()
        if key == '6':
            vr.stop_recording()



    app.run()
```